# What tasks does a memory barrier enforces other than preventing the re-ordering of instructions?

Tags: c, multithreading, x86

I know that a memory barrier prevents the re-ordering of instruction from before to after and from after to before the memory barrier, for example if I have the following instructions:

```
instruction 1
instruction 2
instruction 3
memory barrier
instruction 4
instruction 5
instruction 6
```

These instructions can be executed in the following order:

```
instruction 3
instruction 1
instruction 2
memory barrier
instruction 6
instruction 5
instruction 4
```

But they will never be executed in the following order:

```
instruction 1
instruction 2
instruction 5
memory barrier
instruction 4
instruction 3
instruction 6
```

But I am not sure if the following tasks are also enforced by a memory barrier:

- All pending operations before the memory barrier are completed.
- All data that are still in the cache from write operations before the memory barrier are flushed.

*Note: I am talking about the x86 architecture.*

Comment: There are different sorts of memory barriers, and they are CPU specific. You might want to make this question more precise.

Comment: @FrankHileman: This is the sort that inhibits the re-ordering of certain instructions inside a hyper-threaded CPU so that internal data/registers don't get corrupted.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

Comment: @Frank Hileman I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The definitive source is the [Intel Optimization Reference Manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#optimization). Look at the various fence instructions in Chapter 7, and the discussion on multithreading in Chapter 9.

From Chapter 7: "The MFENCE (MEMORY FENCE) instruction makes it possible for every LOAD/STORE instruction preceding MFENCE in program order to be globally visible before any LOAD/STORE following MFENCE."

There is an interesting [discussion on y-combinator](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8572160) about this. The most interesting comment, for me, was written by a (presumed) author of a concurrent data structure library, [Concurrency Kit](http://concurrencykit.org/): "In my experience, there is no concurrency-related related reason to use mfence on x86. In fact, you'll see that we have code that checks for x86oids and use an atomic RMW instead of non-atomic store/RMW + fence." This begs the question, when do you need the fence instructions? I think it is primarily to simplify code.